# How to determine the order of an elliptic curve group from its parameters?

Tags: elliptic-curves, finite-field, group-theory

Let $\quad E:\; y^2 = x^3 + ax + b \quad$ be an elliptic curve defined over a finite field $\mathbb F_q$ where $q = p^n$, $a,b \in \mathbb F_q$ and $p \neq 2, 3$. By Hasse's theorem we know that the order of $E(\mathbb F_q)$ is in the range $[q+1-2\sqrt{q}, q+1+2\sqrt{q}]$.

Is it possible to determine the order of $E(\mathbb F_q)$ given $a, b, q$ without enumerating the points?

Comment: check 'algorithm of schoof' :) (sry not time for long answer)

Comment: If we are given all the parameters of an elliptic curve (a, b, c, q, h=1) and also the order n.
Can we confirm easily that the order given is the real one using the above mathematics?
n = q+1-t, gives t, then we can test t directly with one of the equations in answers?

Comment: @user108420: We can verify that $t$ matches [Hasses' bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hasse%27s_theorem_on_elliptic_curves), and we can verify that $n\,P=\mathcal O$ for some (or a few) random $P$, showing that $n$ is a multiple of the order of $P$, which must be the case for the actual $n$. For more (like probability of error, how the factorization of $n$ can be used to remove any doubt, reference on elliptic curve parameters validation), you might make a question (after searching if there's not a similar one).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There is a rather deep **polynomial‑time** algorithm for counting the $\mathbb F_q$‑rational points of an elliptic curve published by René **Schoof** in 1985 (with [subsequent improvements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schoof%E2%80%93Elkies%E2%80%93Atkin_algorithm) by Noam **Elkies** and A. O. L. **Atkin**). It is based on two core ideas:

- The number of points is closely linked to a functional equation
  $$ \varphi^2-t\varphi+q = 0 \qquad\in\operatorname{End}(E)$$
  that the *Frobenius endomorphism*
  $$ \varphi\colon\;E\to E,\;\begin{cases}\mathcal O&\mapsto \mathcal O\\(x,y)&\mapsto (x^q,y^q) \end{cases} $$
  satisfies in the endomorphism ring of $E$. If $t\in\mathbb Z$ is chosen such that this equation holds, it is called the *trace of Frobenius* and one can show that
  $$ \#E(\mathbb F_q)=q+1-t \text. $$
  <sup><sub>(The reason $\varphi$ has anything to do with point counting is that it leaves exactly the points with coordinates in $\mathbb F_q$ invariant.)</sub></sup>
- For odd $\ell$, there exist *division polynomials* $\psi_\ell\in\mathbb F_q[x]$ which vanish precisely on the $x$‑coordinates of the finite $\ell$‑torsion points of $E$. Therefore, one can compute $t\bmod\ell$ by checking for which $k\in\{0,\dots,\ell{-}1\}$ the functional equation $\varphi^2-k\varphi+q=0$ holds on a symbolic point $(x,y)$ where $x$ is a hypothetical root of $\psi_\ell$; in other words, this involves evaluating the endomorphism *modulo $\psi_\ell$*. The modular reduction is what makes this step polynomial‑time: The evaluation now works on symbolic points whose size is polynomially bounded in $\ell$, rather than (without any reduction) in $q$. Having computed $t\bmod\ell$ for a sufficiently large set $L$ of odd primes (according to Hasse's theorem, $\prod_{\ell\in L}\ell>4\sqrt q$ is enough), the Chinese remainder theorem can be used to reconstruct the trace of Frobenius $t$, thereby yielding the number of $\mathbb F_q$‑rational points $\#E(\mathbb F_q)$ on $E$.

Of course, there are implementations of (the improved variants of) this algorithm in popular computer algebra systems. Using [SageMath](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/arithmetic_curves/sage/schemes/elliptic_curves/ell_finite_field.html#sage.schemes.elliptic_curves.ell_finite_field.EllipticCurve_finite_field.cardinality), the number of $\mathbb F_{q^n}$‑rational points of an elliptic curve
$$ y^2+a_1xy+a_3y=x^3+a_2x^2+a_4x+a_6 $$
defined over $\mathbb F_q$ can be computed as:

```
EllipticCurve(GF(q), [a1,a2,a3,a4,a6]).cardinality(extension_degree=n)
```

Answer (score 10):

As yyyyyyy mentioned for counting number of points on elliptic curve over $\mathbb F_p$ we can use Elkies method. But for extension of fields  use of this theorem make it so easy:

**Theorem** : Let $E$ be an elliptic curve defined over $F_q$, and let $\#E(F_q ) = q +1−t$.
Then $\#E(F_{q^n} ) = q^n + 1 − V_n$ for all $n ≥ 2$, where $\{V_n\}$ is the sequence defined
recursively by $V_0 = 2, V_1 = t$, and $V_n = V_1V_{n−1}−qV_{n−2}$ for $n ≥ 2$.