# How to find the order of a generator on an elliptic curve?

Tags: elliptic-curves, finite-field, group-theory, elliptic-curve-generation

I was looking out to find optimum generator for an elliptic curve $E$ over a prime field $\mathbb F_p$. I found the following algorithm:

1. Choose random point $P$ on the curve.
2. Find the order of a generator $\ell$.
3. Calculate the number of points $n=\#E(\mathbb F_p)$.
4. Calculate the cofactor $h=n/\ell$.
5. Calculate a generator as $G=[h]P$.

Here I can find $n=\#E(\mathbb F_p)$ using Schoof's algorithm. I need to find $\ell$. How is that possible? How can I find the **order of a generator/base point** of an elliptic curve defined over a prime field?

Comment: This might help: [how to find a primitive point on an elliptic curve](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/866829/how-to-find-primitive-point-on-an-elliptic-curve)

Comment: For cryptographic purposes, the group order should be prime. This means, you should use the subgroup of E with the biggest prime order. That implies that your randomly chosen point P may not be optimal. I would suggest the following algorithm: First factor #E and choose the biggest prime factor q. Then  choose random points P until one of it satisfies P*q = 0.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about general mathematics.

Comment: @fkraiem: As a mathematician, you can surely give me an _exact_ definition what question refers to cryptography and what to general mathematics ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Due to the [Pohlig-Hellman algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pohlig%E2%80%93Hellman_algorithm), the hardness of discrete logarithms is dominated by the largest prime factor $\ell$ of the group order $n$. In particular, one typically works in a subgroup of order $\ell$ of the curve group, since the additional factors $h$ in a generator's order would not significantly contribute to security.

In that, note that $\ell$ depends on the group order $n$: You cannot just decide for some order $\ell$ and then find a point $G$ of that order on an arbitrary fixed curve, since it general such a point will not exist. <sub><sup>(However, there is  the *complex multiplication method*, which *generates* a new curve of given order.)</sup></sub>
Therefore, steps 2 and 3 of the algorithm given in the question must be swapped: You first compute the curve group order $n$, factor it, and determine $\ell$ from the factorization. (And if $\ell$ is too small, you should start over with a new curve. For example, Curve25519 has cofactor $h=8$.)

Other than that, the algorithm is fine, except that you *might* want to check whether $G=\infty$ and start over in that case. However, this only happens with probability $1/\ell$, so it should never occur in practice for cryptographically-sized curves. (Moreover, you would compute and factor the group order only once and find a good $P$ afterwards, but this does not impact the expected runtime much as $P$ usually *is* good at the first try.)

Thus, we have the following algorithm:

1. Compute the curve order $n=\#E(\mathbb F_p)$.
2. Factor $n$ to determine its largest prime factor $\ell$. (Note that you do not need to fully factor $n$: If the remainder after removing a few "small" divisors is not prime, the cofactor is going to be too big anyway.)
3. Compute the cofactor $h=n/\ell$. If $h$ is "too big", start over with a new curve.
4. Choose a random point $P\in E(\mathbb F_p)$ and let $G=[h]P$.
5. If $G$ is the point at infinity, go back to choosing a new $P$. Else, $G$ has order $\ell$.

Comment: Doesn't Pohlig-Hellman only apply to multiplicative groups?

Comment: @user13741 No, Wikipedia is wrong in this respect (and it has long been on my to-do list to improve that article). The algorithm applies to any finite abelian group, as long as a factorization of the group order is known.

Comment: @yyyyyyy Can you point me in a direction on how to compute curve order **n**?

Comment: @RomeoSierra Does [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/27914) help?

Comment: @yyyyyyy Let me check... Thanks a bunch!

Comment: @yyyyyyy That did help indeed! +1