# Is using a cofactor to find a base point only for performance reasons?

Tags: elliptic-curves

For elliptic curve cryptography, the procedure to find a base point that generates a subgroup with order $n$ is:

1. Calculate the order $N$ of the elliptic curve (using Schoof's)
2. Choose $n$. $n$ must be prime and a divisor of $N$
3. Compute cofactor $h = \frac{N}{n}$
4. Choose a random point $P$ on the curve
5. Compute $G = hP$
6. If $G$ is 0, then go back to step 4. Otherwise, you've found a generator with order $n$ and cofactor $h$

[Source](https://andrea.corbellini.name/2015/05/23/elliptic-curve-cryptography-finite-fields-and-discrete-logarithms/)

Is the purpose of the cofactor here solely to increase the efficiency in finding a large sub-group?

I suppose if you didn't use a co-factor and instead tried to brute-force compute whether the random point, $P$, was a generator for a sub-group of size $n$ you would have to do $n$ iterations, which would be impossible on modern computers. But, I want to confirm.

**Edit:** My last paragraph is wrong b/c we can use repeated squaring to calculate $G = nP$

Comment: Dupe of [How to find the order of a generator on an elliptic curve?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/44089/18298)

Comment: @kelalaka, your linked Q&A is not really a duplicate, as it does not discuss the performance reasons at all.  The main thrust of this question here is not •how• to do it, but why:  performance alone or performance+otherReasons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is the purpose of the cofactor here solely to increase the efficiency in finding a large sub-group?

Well, this alternate algorithm would work (assuming $n$ is prime; actually, both algorithms assume $n$ is prime):

4. Choose a random point P on the curve (other than the point at infinity)
5. Compute $G = nP$
6. If $G \ne 0$, go back to step 4.  Otherwise, you've found a generator with order $n$ and cofactor $h$

That algorithm would work; however it is obviously much less efficient; partly because computing $nP$ will be considerably more expensive than computing $hP$ (as we usually have $n \ggg h$), and also in the modified version, you'll take an expected $h$ iterations before finding a point, while in the original algorithm, it's an expected $1 + 1/n$ iterations (that is, the test at the end almost never fails).

Comment: Thanks for the response. Can you explain your last sentence in more detail? (Is modified referring to the version that uses the cofactor or the slower algorithm)?

Comment: Also, with regards to iterations. I'm assuming you mean there is a new iteration each time we guess a new random point, $P$. Given that under both algorithms the point $P$ is chosen randomly, why would there be less guesses in the original algorithm?

Comment: @Roymunson After picking a random point that satisfies the curve equation, an iteration of your algorithm will succeed $N-h$ out of $N$ times (i.e. almost certainly), and poncho's alternate algorithm (if you consider the iteration to begin at the time of choosing a random point but before the infinity check) will with each iteration succeed only $n-1$ out of $N$ times (i.e. approx. $1$ out of $h$ times). The advantage of poncho's algorithm is that it won't exclude any valid possibilities

Comment: @knaccc: actually, the original algorithm won't exclude any valid possibilities either; in fact, it'll generate all possible generators with equal probability

Comment: @poncho thanks for pointing that out. Now I think about it, that does make perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

This is an empirical result to complement Poncho's answer;

Take Curve25519 which has a cofactor $8$ as the order $n$ of the group factors as

$\small{n = 2^3 * 7237005577332262213973186563042994240857116359379907606001950938285454250989}$

- $h = 8 $
- $q = n/8$

We use SageMath and SageMath `random_element` function in which [it may return the identity element $\mathcal{O}$ of the curve](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/68603/18298) ( the of chance getting it is negligible) , on Curve25519 $\mathcal{O} 
 = (0:1:0)$ on Weierstrass form.

```
import time

def randomBasePointByCofactor(E,identity,cofactor):
    
    s = time.time()
    ci = 0
    n = E.order()
    for i in range(1,10000):
        P = E.random_element()
        if cofactor*P != identity:
            ci = ci +1
    e = time.time()
    print("time elapsed on randomBasePointByCofactor", e-s)
    return (ci)
        
def randomBasePointByOrder(E,identity,cofactor):
    
    s = time.time()
    ci = 0
    n = Integer(E.order() / cofactor)
    for i in range(1,10000):
        P = E.random_element()
        if n*P == identity:
            ci = ci +1

    e = time.time()
    print("time elapsed on randomBasePointByOrder", e-s)
    return (ci)    

p = 0x7fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffed
K = GF(p)
A = K(0x76d06)
B = K(0x01)
E = EllipticCurve(K, ((3 - A^2)/(3 * B^2), (2 * A^3 - 9 * A)/(27 * B^3)))

IP = E((0,1,0))
Bound = 10000

print(" number of found generators =" , randomBasePointByCofactor(E,IP,8), "/", Bound)

print(" number of found generators =", randomBasePointByOrder(E,IP,8),"/", Bound)
```

A sample result is

```
time elapsed on randomBasePointByCofactor 1.9164307117462158
 number of found generators = 9999 / 10000
time elapsed on randomBasePointByOrder 64.77565383911133
 number of found generators = 1267 / 10000
```

Therefore

- the cofactor method is faster ~32 times faster in the experiments.

  We can explain this in simple terms as; $8$ requires 4 doublings and 1 addition, whereas $n$ requires 251 doublings and 125 addition with naive [double-and-algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_curve_point_multiplication#Double-and-add). This gives ~75 times more calculations if we assume doubling and additions have the same speed which they are not.
- the cofactor method produces more generators than the order method since the  $1/8$ of the random elements from $8\cdot q$ falls into the large prime $q$ of the Curve25519.

**Therefore, the cofactor method is preferable.**

Comment: Thank you, this script was extremely helpful for seeing the theory in action.

Comment: That was the reason that one need to implement to see. Even Paul Erdös had problem on [Monty Hall problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monty_Hall_problem) until they saw computer simulation..